# How to add parameters to IN clause in spring data repository native query

Tags: sql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

folks,

I have a problem finding a way to send parameters for IN clause in a native query through Spring data repository. I tried sending list of strings, concatenated 
 and formatted strings... nothing helped

Comment: I think you are supposed to separate question from answer using the checkbox at the bottom for that : https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

```
    @Repository
public interface Repo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Log, Long>
{
    @Query(value = QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
    List<OrderExecutionLog> findTop1OrderByInitiatedAsc(String[] types);

    String QUERY = "SELECT log.* " +
            "FROM log" +
            "WHERE `type` IN (?3) ";
}
```

I tried several variations with a list or concatenated strings and so on ... but a simple array gave me the desired result. I think that the Spring community need to take a look at this simple issue i encountered.

Good luck. Hope this helps someone like me :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have list of strings which are to be passed as parameter for an IN clause, refer below

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_SOME_NAME IN :someList", nativeQuery = true)
List<T> getList(List<String> someList);
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to contain an explanation?